# wordpress one-page website with different php pages

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to build a wordpress website. I'd like to have a one-page design. I have built 5 pages 
each one has its own php file. How can I do to concatenate the 5 pages in one single page?
Thank you in advance for your help,
Fabiana

Answer (score 0):

You may not need to use multiple pages at all but implement inbuilt function for wordpress like shortcodes, or use posts and make multiple queries to the post. You can then design your page (1) in sections and make sure to make `$loop = new WP_Query( $args );` to enable multiple queries on the same page. These queries would/should only query post not pages.

Section 1 Layout

---

```
$args1 = shortcode_atts (array(
                    'tag' => 'post-type',
                    'post_type'=> 'post',
                    'cat' => '', // Category ID
                    'posts_per_page' => 1,
                    'bgimageurl' => ''), $atts);
                $query1 = new WP_Query( $args2 );
// The Loop
                    while ( $query1->have_posts() ) {
                        $query1->the_post();
                       the_content();
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Section 2 Layout

---

```
$args2 = shortcode_atts (array(
                    'tag' => 'userchoice',
                    'post_type'=> 'post',
                    'cat' => '', // Category ID
                    'posts_per_page' => 1,
                    'bgimageurl' => ''), $atts);
                $query2 = new WP_Query( $args2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [this plugin for wordpress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-fullpage/) which provides a way to create full screen scrolling pages by using [fullPage.js plugin](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/).